# Can't change X-Xsrf-Token header in axios post request

Tags: javascript, spring, axios, typescript-typings

I am trying to post a request to a Java Spring backend using axios but I can't change the `X-Xsrf-Token` header which axios automatically sets on every request. I have tried to use an interceptor like this;

```
let token = $('meta[name="_csrf"]').attr('content') as string;
// @ts-ignore
let _csrf_header = $('meta[name="_csrf_header"]').attr('content') as string;
// @ts-ignore
window.axios = axios;
if (token) {
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
   console.log(_csrf_header, token);
    // axios.defaults.headers.common[_csrf_header] = token;
    axios.interceptors.request.use(
        config => {
            config.headers[_csrf_header] = token;
            return config;
        },
        error => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );
}
```

I have also tried to set the `X-Xsrf-Token` manually but still I see a different string added to the header. I can't replace it.

```
            axios.post('/text/read?name='+textName, {}, {
                headers: {
                    "X-XSRF-TOKEN": "changed!"
                }
            }).then(res => {
                console.log (res);
                if (res.status==200){
                    resolve(res.data );
                }else {
                    reject(res.data);
                }
            }).catch((err: any) => {
                console.error("Enable to load note", err.response.data);
                reject(err.response.data);
            });
```

I am not sure where the default string comes from either.

I can change it when I use a `new XMLHttpRequest()` and `fetch` request but not with axios